# Is there a word for someone who wants to die?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an existing word or even a new word formed from latin/greek/french/etc. roots that means "someone that wants to die" or "someone that wants to be killed" or something along those lines. Thanks!

Comment: The obvious choice would be *suicidal*...?  Is that not what you want for some reason?

Comment: i use 'mortalist' but i don't know why

Comment: @JonMarkPerry "Mortalist" has quite a different meaning. Per OED - *A person who believes that the soul is mortal and dies with the body; an adherent of mortalism.*

Comment: One might say "morbid", though it doesn't exactly carry the stated implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Suicidal**
> [soo-uh-sahyd-l]/
> adjective
>
> 1. pertaining to, involving, or suggesting suicide.
> 2. tending or leading to suicide.

or

> **Masochist**
> [mas-uh-kist]/
> noun
>
> 1. Psychiatry. a person who has masochism, the condition in which sexual or other gratification depends on one's suffering physical pain or humiliation.
> 2. a person who is gratified by pain, degradation, etc., that is self-imposed or imposed by others.

or

> **Self-destructive**
> [self-di-struhk-tiv, self-]/
> adjective
>
> 1. harmful, injurious, or destructive to oneself.
> 2. reflecting or exhibiting suicidal desires or drives.

or

> **Cupio dissolvi**
>
> The phrase, literally meaning "I wish to be dissolved", expresses the Christian desire to leave the earthly life and join Christ in eternal life. It has played an important role in discussions on the topic of suicide from the Middle Ages to the early Modern period. Over time, however, especially where national idioms derive from Romance languages, the phrase has acquired more secular and profane meanings and uses, expressing such concepts as the rejection of existence and the masochistic desire for self-destruction.
> [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupio_dissolvi)

Comment: Masochists don't want to die. The point of their pain is, after all, sexual gratification,

Comment: It is a rectangle:square relationship. All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares. All people who want to kill themselves are masochists (deriving some form of relief through their death), but not all masochists are suicidal. I use all only for the purposes of demonstrating the analogy. I am sure there are cases where this is less discernable. But certainly in the OP, by referring to "wanting to be killed", this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a name for the person, but for their feeling.

***Death wish*** -- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/death-wish)

> 1. desire for one's own death or for the death of another.
> 2. (Psychiatry) a suicidal desire, manifested by passivity, withdrawal, and absorption in nihilistic thoughts, that may eventually lead to suicidal behavior.

From *Life On The Run* by Ayaan Hirsi Ali

> People ask me if I have some kind of **death wish**, to keep saying the things I do.

The answer to your question is just [***suicidal person***](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Suicidal_person).

Comment: Someone who wants to die would be called suicidal. A "death wish" is more of someone acting in a way that is likely to cause them to be killed.

Comment: @PaulRobinson Someone who wants to *kill themself* would be called suicidal, someone who just wishes for death to happen along may fairly be said to have a death wish. 'Death wish' *can* be applied to someone who is behaving recklessly or without regard to their own safety, but it is generally figurative in that sense as people don't actually believe that Base Jumpers or whatever *actually* wish to die.

Comment: Someone who wants to die is not suicidal. They could be 'just' 
depressed.  Someone who is at a high risk  to commit suicide is suicidal. Ooops, didn't see that @Spagirl made a similar  point.

Answer (score -4):

The word I associate with the milieu you describe is . . .

> nihilist

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nihilist?s=t

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this isn't correct - nihilists don't explicitly *want* to die, they just don't care.  I think the OP was looking for synonyms to 'suicidal'.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Why do you think that's what MagicalHacker is looking for? He cites 2 circumstances, wanting 'to die' and wanting 'to be killed'. Neither of those suggest the active step of 'self-killing'.

Comment: @Spagirl good point. But I still don't think nihilist is what they wanted..

Comment: Yup, agree there.